# About the indices in subsequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

In the definition of a subsequence https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Subsequence#Definition

I am asking if it is still possible to consider $n_{r}>r$
just like the subsequence of primes, i.e., $p_{r}>r$

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh: Just the indices in the subsequences are greater than the indices in the original sequence.

Comment: @Helena: All $4$ examples in the link you reference have $n_r > r$ for all $r$, so for those examples, the $n$-th subsequence subscript is greater than $n$.

Comment: @quasi: Yes. I know, that for those examples. I am asking about the general case.

Comment: Well, $n_r = r$ is also possible. Every sequence is a subsequence of itself.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh: I am asking about the strict inequality. Yes. the case of equation is possible.

Comment: Indeed it is possible. Consider $n_r = 2r$. Then for all $r \in \mathbb{N}$, $n_r > r$.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh: This is just an example not the general case of any subsequence..

Comment: My previous comment on equality meant that in general strict inequality is not possible.

Comment: @Helena: Since the sequence $n_r$ is strictly increasing, then unless $n_r=r$, we must have $n_r >r$. Moreover, as soon as $n_r > r$ for some $r=r_0$, then $n_r > r$ for all $r > r_0$.

Comment: @quasi: Can you convert this into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since the sequence $(n_r)=n_1,n_2,n_3,...$ is a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers, then for each positive integer $r$, unless $n_r=r$, we must have $n_r >r$. Moreover, as soon as $n_r > r$ for some $r=r_0$, then $n_r > r$ for all $r \ge r_0$.

But as Aniruddha Deshmukh pointed out in the comments, we can have $n_r=r$ for some (possibly all) values of $r$. For example, if the original sequence is $x_1,x_2,x_3,...$, then the subsequence $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_5,x_6,x_7,...$ has $n_r=r$ for $r\le 3$.